# how to count specifc values, even if there are no results?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create an array with 10 elements that is filled with the count of all 10 possible options.

```
number_count = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0])

unique, count = np.unique(number_count, return_counts=True)
dict(zip(unique,count))
count_array = count /10
```

(the `number_count` array has been changed as the values are coming from a txt file instead of it being hard coded).

The way I have counted the elements I am returning all 7 unique occurrences of the values, but I am trying to include options for (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) even if there are 0 occurrences of a specific value.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use `numpy.unique` to count specific unique values instead of just the unique occurrences, or am I better of using some other form of counting?

Comment: Are you looking an array `count_array` or a dict `dict(zip(unique,count))`

Comment: sorry if i miss understand the question. but the goal is to store the count in a dict then insert the values into the count array.

Comment: Values of `number_count` always between 0 to 9?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of zeros of the length you want and just add your counts indexed by the return value of `np.unique`

```
import numpy as np

number_count = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,9,0,0,0,1])

counts = np.zeros(10, dtype=int)

unique, count = np.unique(number_count, return_counts=True)
counts[unique] += count

counts
# array([4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

This avoids the temporary dictionary. If you actually want the dict you can create it from the list with :

```
dict(enumerate(counts))
# {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1}
```

Comment: My bad. But in case he wants to use values more than 10 this hack can be useful `np.zeros(np.max(number_count))` but it's memory inefficient(I just started learning NumPy) there may be a better way.